# Specific line of code runs from file or console but not from a function

Tags: r

I have a line of code at the top of one of my open scripts which prints out a sorted list of my environment objects together with their sizes (the division is there so it returns in MB instead of bytes):

```
sort(sapply(ls(),function(x){object.size(get(x)) / 2**20}))
```

And every time I want a list of my stuff, I have to go back to a specific part of one file to run this line of code. Whenever I try to put it into a function, it gives me the following error:

```
 Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic
```

So how would I be able to toss this line into a function so instead of having to find the line, I could just run the function for it to print out the thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ListMyStuff <- function() {
    sort(sapply(ls(, envir=.GlobalEnv),function(x){object.size(get(x)) / 2**20}))
}
```

When you run `ls()` from a function, it looks in the local environment, i.e objects you created inside the function.